# Child interfering with mouse wheel event propagation

Tags: wpf, scrollviewer, mousewheel

I have a fairly complex front end on an WPF App and to make things simpler as they are reused heavily,  I've broken it into Uaer controls

```
<ScrollViewer>
  <TreeVeiw>
     <TreeVeiwIterm>
        <UserControl>
          <Grid>
            <Label>
            <UserControl>
              <Grid>
                Buttols, images, labels, etc
```

The problem is one or more of these children is handling the mouse wheels event before the scroll view gets it so the app wont scroll.

which is it and how do i bypass the interference?

EDIT
.Net 3.5 and VS2008

Comment: so far checking each object to see if it has a scroll bar that's not visible but so far not found one.
I know that ListViews include a scroll viewer so intercept scroll events so thats what i'm assuming is happening here but as i don't have a listview in the object tree it must be a different object (probably the treeview but if so its completely hidden)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sigh.....
Knew it was simple, the tree view does contain the scroll-viewer but the its not exposed and is activated automatically, there for removing the containing scroll-viewer activates the scroll-viewer inside the tree-view.

Luckily the removed Scroll-Viewer was only there because i didn't know that the tree-view contained one